# Maven: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on Jboss

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, maven-plugin, jboss6.x

Firstable sorry for my English, I have a Maven Project which is a Web Service (packaged into a war file)

I use this pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ec.gob.turismo</groupId>
<artifactId>mintur-bpm</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>mintur-bpm</name>
<description>Servicio Web que interactúa con los procesos del negocio</description>
<properties>
    <jbpm.version>6.0.1.Final</jbpm.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.5.Final</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ec.gob.turismo.siete.establecimientos</groupId>
        <artifactId>establecimientos-dto</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jbpm.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie.remote</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-services-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jbpm.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

I use JbossEAP 6.3, when I type mvn clean install, maven generates the war file and copy inside the standalone directory. Next when I see my console in my eclipse I see this error:

```
[DEBUG] Executing deployment
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18.643s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Oct 02 16:49:19 COT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/358M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.5.Final:deploy (default) on project mintur-bpm: Deployment failed and was rolled back. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.5.Final:deploy (default) on project mintur-bpm: Deployment failed and was rolled back.
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.plugin.common.DeploymentExecutionException: Deployment failed and was rolled back.
at org.jboss.as.plugin.deployment.standalone.StandaloneDeployment.execute(StandaloneDeployment.java:180)
at org.jboss.as.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.executeDeployment(AbstractDeployment.java:121)
at org.jboss.as.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.doExecute(AbstractDeployment.java:146)
at org.jboss.as.plugin.deployment.AbstractAppDeployment.doExecute(AbstractAppDeployment.java:70)
at org.jboss.as.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.execute(AbstractDeployment.java:111)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Finally in Jboss log (server.log), I see this stack trace:

```
16:49:17,770 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."mintur-bpm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."mintur-bpm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Error al procesar la fase INSTALL de deployment "mintur-bpm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ec.gob.turismo.siete.serviciosweb.bmp.BusinessProcessManagement from [Module "deployment.mintur-bpm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.metadata.MetadataBuilder.createDDEndpoint(MetadataBuilder.java:241)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.metadata.MetadataBuilder.build(MetadataBuilder.java:82)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.DescriptorDeploymentAspect.generateMetadataFromDeployment(DescriptorDeploymentAspect.java:135)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.DescriptorDeploymentAspect.start(DescriptorDeploymentAspect.java:68)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.AspectDeploymentProcessor.deploy(AspectDeploymentProcessor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ec.gob.turismo.siete.serviciosweb.bmp.BusinessProcessManagement from [Module "deployment.mintur-bpm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.metadata.MetadataBuilder.createDDEndpoint(MetadataBuilder.java:237)
    ... 10 more

16:49:17,781 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 29) JBAS015870: La implementaci▒n de "mintur-bpm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" se deshizo con el siguiente mensaje de fallo:
{"JBAS014671: Servicios fallidos" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"mintur-bpm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"mintur-bpm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Error al procesar la fase INSTALL de deployment \"mintur-bpm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\"
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ec.gob.turismo.siete.serviciosweb.bmp.BusinessProcessManagement from [Module \"deployment.mintur-bpm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ec.gob.turismo.siete.serviciosweb.bmp.BusinessProcessManagement from [Module \"deployment.mintur-bpm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
16:49:19,100 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015877: Se detuvo la implementaci▒nmintur-bpm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war (runtime-name: mintur-bpm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war) en 1317ms
```

The error above says that a Class is not found in my war file, which is incorrect because I have opened many times the war file and there are all the classes inside.

Could you help me please, because I can't find a solution?

Thanks.

PD: If you need more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault, this package does not exist in my war file, that's why the error:

```
ec.gob.turismo.siete.serviciosweb.bmp.BusinessProcessManagement
```

The correct package is:

```
ec.gob.turismo.serviciosweb.bmp.BusinessProcessManagement
```

Aditional I have placed a web.xml file that makes references to the class that implements the BusinessProcessManagement interface.

Thanks.